# Power series and radius of convergence of $\sin z$ about $1$ - complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

Here's a problem I'm stuck on:

Determine the power series and radius of convergence for $f(z) = \sin z$ centered at $1$.

I'm unsure as to what to do with the fact that it is centered about $1$ in terms of the power series. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hint for determining the power series: $f(z) = \sin ((z-1) + 1) = \cos 1 \sin (z-1) + \sin 1 \cos (z-1)$.

Answer (score 1):

$z\mapsto \sin z$ is an entire function, so the radius is infinite.

If $\displaystyle f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n(z-a)^n$ then the radius of convergence is the distance from $a$ to the point in $\mathbb C$ nearest to $a$ to which the domain of $f$ cannot be extended while $f$ remains holomorphic. If there is no such point, then the radius is infinite.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $a_{n}=f^{(n)}(1)/n!$, and $|f^{(n)}(1)|$ is either $\sin 1$ or $\cos 1$. We know that $1/R=\limsup_{n}|a_{n}|^{1/n}\leq M\limsup_{n}1/(n!)^{1/n}=0$, so $R=\infty$. The fact that $(n!)^{1/n}\rightarrow\infty$ follows by $n!>(n/2)^{n/2}$ for large $n$.